# Azure restrict access to web app by ip range

Tags: azure

I have deployed a node js web app on azure and I want to restrict access to it by ip address. I have done a similar thing easily before in AWS with security groups. However, I am at present on the free dev platform and when I got to the ip restrictions setting tab in the Azure portal gui it says I need to upscale the app because ip restriction is not available on the current platform. What I'm build needs very minimal resources. It is a one page internal static newsletter. What is the minimal resource on azure I need to use to get the ip restriction or is there another route I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal resource you need to configure IP restrictions within the Portal is **B1**:

[image]

Read here how to configure it: 
[Azure App Service Static IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-SI/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions)

---

**Note:** You can also enable IP Restrictions on the *free* tier by adding a web.config using the [IP Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/) setting. Working sample:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security> 
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false"> 
            <clear/> 
             <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53" allowed="true"/> 
        </ipSecurity>  
    </security>
</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Now all you have to do is to put the web.config to your *wwwroot* directory. You can either include the web.config in your deployment or you manually add it using the Kudu engine.

Just replace `<YOURSITE>` with your actual site and follow the link:

```
https://<YOURSITE>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell
```

[image]

If you now browse the app using an unlisted IP you will get the following error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Comment: thank you. do you know what the estimated cost is based on for that tier?

Comment: 47,02 € as you see in the screenshot ;-). Not: You do scale the app service plan which is a container to host one or multiple sites. So you can host multiple additional sites there without additional costs

Comment: but do you know how that is calculated as it says "(Estimated)" e.g. it might not be exactly that amount if you only use a fraction of the resources.

Comment: No, its not consumption but time based. Take a look at the pricing calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Comment: any other cheaper ways of doing it?

Comment: @weaveoftheride Sure, I was dumb not showing you have to do that in the free tier. I edited my answer.